# Can Spring and Struts run in the same JVM?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jvm, struts

**Does anyone have any warnings against using Spring on an app server that's already running Struts?**  I'm a little new to both Struts and Spring, so I'm not sure if they share any of the same dependencies.  I've just joined a new team and we run some pretty critical web apps with Struts.  For what it's worth with my environment the server is **Apache Tomcat 5.5.25** and we're working with the **Java JDK 1.5.0_12** .  I wouldn't be necessarily trying to use any of the same resources (i.e. Database connections), but I wouldn't want some JRE component to blowup due to my application.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The most simple answer I can provide is 'yes, they can run together'. At work our project uses Struts on its legacy parts and Spring MVC on the rewritten ones. Don't know it if involved any kind of dirty workaround, as I never used Struts. Guess you can go ahead without much trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sure you can do it. See for example.

http://www.javabeat.net/articles/70-integrating-struts-with-spring-1.html

http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/struts-2-spring-2-jpa-ajax.html

Comment: Alex, let me clarify.  If I've got a tomcat instance with 1 site inside {tomcat}\webapps\StrutsApp\ and I want to make a new one in {tomcat}\webapps\SpringApp\ , do you think there will be any issue?  I wasn't sure if Struts grabs a hold of any web request that comes in, or if it's on a per "webapp" basis (i.e. different sites as children of the webapps directory).

It sounds like "Yes" is the answer, though?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem to run both together, I`ve already done that and was great!